# Upgrading a varchar column to enum type in postgresql

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, ddl

We have a varchar column in a table, that we need to upgrade to enum type.

All the values in the varchar column are valid values in the enumeration. There is no null values in the varchar column.

```
ALTER TABLE tableName
   ALTER COLUMN varcharColumn TYPE enum_type
```

**ERROR: column "varcharColumn" cannot be cast to type enum_type
SQL state: 42804**

The round about way is to

1. Create another new column with enum type.
2. Update the enum type column with the varchar column after typecasting.
3. Drop the varchar column.
4. Rename the enum type column name to the varchar column name.

Is there a better way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You need to define a cast to be used because there is no default cast available.

If all values in the `varcharColumn` comply with the enum definition, the following should work:

```
alter table foo 
  ALTER COLUMN varcharColumn TYPE enum_type using varcharColumn::enum_type;
```

I personally don't like enums because they are quite unflexible. I prefer a check constraint on a varchar column if I want to restrict the values in a column. Or - if the list of values changes often and is going to grow - a good old "lookup table" with a foreign key constraint.

Comment: Enums are also more problematic when working with some client apps than lookup tables or simple constrained columns are. As anyone who's had the dubious pleasure of working with enums in JPA/Hibernate knows.

Comment: Thanks a_horse_with_no_name! Though I found out the solution from documentation, your explanation is quite comprehensive and useful.

Comment: I recently needed to reorganize enums by moving them to schemas were it makes more sense for them to be. As such, the tables which rely on the enums needed to have their types "changed" to point to the new location for the enum. I did it as follows, with a double-cast: `alter table my_schema.my_column alter column sale_item_status type my_schema.my_column_enum
using ((my_column::text)::my_schema.my_column_enum)` -- HTH anyone else with a enum "problem" of this nature

Comment: why they are unflexible if you can at any time add or remove them?

Comment: @Dejell [You can't remove a value from a Postgres enum](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/datatype-enum.html#id-1.5.7.15.8), only add or rename. It requires administrative access to  change an enum vs normal CRUD access to change a join table. A join table can be altered with normal CRUD tools and the job of keeping it updated handed to a non-DBA.

Comment: the answers critique on enum misses a great +: they are ordered, eg good for loglevel

Comment: For completeness, remember to remove any irrelevant `CHECK` constraints on the old column before the type change.

Answer (score 7):

Got it.

```
ALTER TABLE tableName
   ALTER COLUMN varcharColumn TYPE enum_type
    USING varcharColumn::enum_type
```

will update it successfully.

Answer (score 0):

you as well might consider domain type if you dont need the enum ordering property and are offput by missing delete enum value.
Domain types are user-denfiend types + constraints, which makes x out of a selection possible via `CHECK` & co and as such not so 'unwieldy like enums.

Typical enum is eg log levels, while domain eg email text input validation with the field being present in many tables.