# Upgrading enum type column to varchar in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, enums

I have an enum type column in my table . I have now decided to make it a varchar type and put some constraint.

Q1) Which  is a good practice : to have enums or to put constarint on the column.

Q2) How to change my enum type column to varchar. Just opposite to this question [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15655820/upgrading-a-varchar-column-to-enum-type-in-postgresql) .
I tried using this:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename ALTER COLUMN columnname  TYPE VARCHAR
```

But this gives me the error : `No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.`

This is the table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE tablename (
    id1 TEXT NOT NULL,
    id2 VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    enum_field table_enum,
    modified_on TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
    modified_by VARCHAR(100),
    PRIMARY key (id1, id2)
);
```

Comment: It works for me. Can you expand the question with `CREATE TYPE` and `CREATE TABLE` statements so I can reproduce the problem?

Comment: What happens if you try: `ALTER TABLE tablename ALTER COLUMN columnname TYPE VARCHAR USING columnname::text` ? The message suggests that it can’t convert your enum, which is technically a type, to `varchar`, presumably because enum is not a simple type. You may have some success type casting to text. From https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altertable.html: “A USING clause must be provided if there is no implicit or assignment cast from old to new type”.

Comment: @manngo operator does not exist: character varying = table_enum : this is the error that i get when i run your suggested command . table_enum is the enum field of my table .

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe this is how i created my table : CREATE TABLE tablename
(
 id1 TEXT NOT NULL,
 id2 VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
 enum_field table_enum,
 modified_on TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
 modified_by VARCHAR(100),
 PRIMARY key (id1, id2)
);

Comment: @SouravPrem Can you also post the definition of `table_enum` ?

Comment: Still works for me. What is the `CREATE TYPE` statement for `table_enum`?

Comment: Name      | Internal name | Size |   Elements   | 
---------------+---------------+------+--------------+
 exposure_enum | exposure_enum | 4    | SELF  +|
               |               |      | ALL         +|
               |               |      | REJECT   +|
               |               |      | NO-ACTION|

@LaurenzAlbe this is the definition . {got by using \dT+ table_enum}

Comment: How to print table in comment  :P

Comment: I still cannot reproduce the problem. What you should do is to edit the question and add a sequence of `CREATE` and `INSERT` statements that reliably reproduce the error. Also, you should mention which version of PostgreSQL you are using.

Comment: When you have this working, what values do you want in your altered column? The text (`SELF|ALL|REJECT|NO-ACTION`) or a number?

Comment: I have added your enum to your question. However, I don’t see the owner name, and it seems to be describing a different enum (`exposure_enum`)?

Comment: These values only (SELF |ALL |REJECT|NOGACTION)

Comment: That is not the error.. I was trying to produce the error so that value is exposure_enum is just another name.  I have omitted the owner.

Answer (score 9):

For future reference: I had the similar issue with altering enum type and I got the same error message as the one above. In my case, the issue was caused by having a partial index that referenced a column that was using that enum type.

Comment: Same with the check constraints and all that.

Comment: This solved issue for me, thanks!

Comment: So I have to delete referenced indexes and constraints? That's awful

Comment: This was my exact issue too and had no clue the constraint was the issue!

Answer (score 3):

As for best practice, it is best if you define a separate table of possible values, and make your column a foreign key to this table. This has the following benefits:

- The new table can not only have the specific key as a type, it can have additional columns with details such as a friendly name, meaning of the type or more information
- Changing the possible values is a matter of manipulating data rows (`INSERT`,`UPDATE` or `DELETE`) which is more accessible and manageable than changing constraints or enum values.