# how to change type of column in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have column is 'enum_type'. And i using query:

```
ALTER TABLE subscriptions
ALTER COLUMN subscribable_type TYPE enum('User', 'Organization');
```

to change type from string to enum. But it not work and fail:

> [42704] ERROR: type "enum" does not exist

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15655820/upgrading-a-varchar-column-to-enum-type-in-postgresql

Comment: You shouldn't be using enums to begin with. Use a proper lookup table with a foreign key. If you just want to limit the allowed values, use a check constraint instead.

Comment: You can use it like as:

CREATE TYPE subscription_type AS ENUM (
  'User', 
  'Organization');
ALTER TABLE subscriptions
   ALTER COLUMN subscribable_type TYPE subscription_type
    USING subscribable_type::subscription_type;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to do it in two steps:

```
CREATE TYPE sub_type
   AS ENUM ('User', 'Organization');

ALTER TABLE subscriptions
   ALTER subscribable_type TYPE sub_type USING subscribable_type::sub_type;
```

Comment: That's great! Thanks! :D