# insert enum datatype via pandas.to_sql

Tags: python, postgresql, pandas, sqlalchemy

I have a pandas dataframe as follows:

```
In [93]: df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 'a'], [2, 'b'], [3, 'a']], columns=['val', 'types'])

In [94]: df
Out[94]:
   val types
0    1    a
1    2    b
2    3    a

In [95]: df.dtypes
Out[95]:
val       int64
types    object
dtype: object

# convert the 'types' column to category
In [96]: df.types = pd.Categorical(df.types)
```

Assuming I already have a postgres table with column `types` as *ENUM*, how do I insert data into my DB via sqlachemy types with pandas `to_sql` method?

I tried this but couldn't make it work:

```
In [101]: class myEnum(enum.Enum):
     ...:     a = 1
     ...:     b = 2
     ...:

In [102]: from sqlalchemy.types import *

In [103]: sql_dtypes = {'val' : SmallInteger(), 'types': Enum(myEnum)}

In [104]: df.to_sql('tablename', conn, if_exists='replace', index=False,
                    dtype=sql_dtypes)
```

running which gives me the following error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) type "myEnum" already 
exists

[SQL: "CREATE TYPE myEnum AS ENUM ('a', 'b')"] (Background on this 
error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/f405)
```

Specifying with the `schema` option from `pd.io.json.build_table_schema` too didn't help.

Comment: why not`if_exists="append"`? so pandas wouldn't recreate the table for you

Answer (score 2):

To handle postgresql enum in a `pandas.to_sql` we should do the following :

Trying to explain with a relatable example for easier readability.

In database DDL outside of pandas. So Postgresql Enum is created outside of pandas scope.

```sql
-- In postgresql
CREATE TYPE bank_transaction_type AS ENUM
     ('withdrawal', 'deposit');

CREATE TABLE bank_transactions (
    bank_name text,
    reference_no text, 
    transaction_date date, 
    transaction_type bank_transaction_type, 
);
```

In pandas script

```py
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import ENUM

BankTransactionType = ENUM("withdrawal", "deposit", 
                           name="bank_transaction_type",
                           create_type=False)

def save_df_to_postgres(df: DataFrame, table_name: str):
    try:
        sql_dtypes = {"transaction_type": BankTransactionType}
        df.to_sql(
            name=table_name, 
            con=settings.sqlalchemy_database_url,
            if_exists="append",
            index=False,
            dtype=sql_dtypes,
            method='multi'
        )
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"Error while saving to postgres: {e}")
```

Few pointers :

- `ENUM` from `sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql` and not the python's Enum
- `sql_dtypes` is defining only subset of columns and not all the column types. This should help save manual efforts
- In `to_sql` - `dtype=sql_dtypes` is assigned with dictionary mapping to sqlalchemy enum type
- In `BankTransactionType` creation we mention - `create_type=False` to skip creation of this type. This is taken care outside of `pandas.to_sql`

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround I found for now from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15655926/3282392) is to write the datatype as `varchar` first and later convert it to `enum`.

```
In [104]: df.to_sql('tablename', conn, if_exists='replace', index=False,
                    dtype=sql_dtypes)

In [105]: conn.execute("""ALTER TABLE tablename 
                          ALTER COLUMN types TYPE myEnum using types::myEnum;""")
```

But I hope there's a better solution.